# Using an input value to activated a named sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'find first empty row in sheet
iRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

What am I missing, My data gets overridden because it wont advance to the next empty row?

Comment: It's pretty simple. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to start you off:

```
Sub SheetPicker()
   Dim msg As String
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim V As Variant

   msg = vbCrLf
   For Each sh In Sheets
      msg = msg & sh.Name & vbCrLf
   Next sh
   Do
      V = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please pick from:" & msg, Type:=2)
      If V = False Then
         Exit Sub
      End If
      If Exists(CStr(V)) Then
         Sheets(V).Select
         Exit Sub
      End If
   Loop
End Sub

Function Exists(s As String) As Boolean
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Exists = False
   For Each sh In Sheets
      If sh.Name = s Then
         Exists = True
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next sh
End Function
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version avoids hidden sheets:

```
Sub SheetPicker()
   Dim msg As String
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim V As Variant

   msg = vbCrLf
   For Each sh In Sheets
      If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
         msg = msg & sh.Name & vbCrLf
      End If
   Next sh
   Do
      V = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please pick from:" & msg, Type:=2)
      If V = False Then
         Exit Sub
      End If
      If Exists(CStr(V)) Then
         Sheets(V).Select
         Exit Sub
      End If
   Loop
End Sub

Function Exists(s As String) As Boolean
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Exists = False
   For Each sh In Sheets
      If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
         If sh.Name = s Then
            Exists = True
            Exit Function
         End If
      End If
   Next sh
End Function
```

Comment: You forgot to add `Sheets(V).Visible = xlSheetVisible` before `Sheets(V).Select` :) The code will error out if the sheet is hidden :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout  Good point! .....................re-coded to avoid Hidden sheets.

Comment: But why avoid it? What if the user wants to select the hidden sheet?

Comment: All you had to do was add that one line to your existing code :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I assumed that if the sheet was Hidden, the Owner does not want the User to get to it....................I will let the OP resolve this.

Comment: ++ Fair enough :) As it is you have given too much on the plate :D

Comment: Already upvoted the post, however I thought of [THIS](http://wikisend.com/download/648802/Untitled.png) which you or the OP may like ;) Anyways it's almost 5 AM. I am off to bed. Gnite

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. Now, I am adding this to a command click on a userform that will add data to that selected sheet. How do I reference the selected sheet? I will try to add a portion of the existing code. Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
'find first empty row in sheet
iRow = Worksheets("???????").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

With ws
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox40.Value
  TextBox40.Value = Format(TextBox40.Value, "m/dd/yy")
  'TextBox40.Value = CDate(TextBox40)
  .Cells(i..................

Comment: @George  I would need to see your code to answer that.

Comment: @George  If you ran my code and Selected the worksheet then replace `Set ws = Worksheets("?????")` with `Set ws = ActiveSheet`

Comment: THANK YOU. I am so new to this and I am trying to teach myself.

Comment: Another minor obstacle. What commandcan i add under thisworkbook so the first thing it does is run sheetpicker then i have it open my userform?

Comment: You would have the Open event macro *Call* SheetPicker and then *Show* the userform.